# New Column in a table based on the values of slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible in Power BI to create a new column in a table returning the value selected in a slicer?

Right now, I have added the threshold manually, but I would like the values to change if the user selects another threshold in the slicer. So if the threshold is 7 the column will be fill with "7" values so the selected Agent column changes accordingly

Selected Agent = IF('Agent Ranking'[Ranking Agent] <= 'Agent Ranking'[Agent Threshold], 1,0)

Could this be done?

[image]

Comment: No, not as a Calculated Column. Calculated Columns and Calculated Tables are calculated at dataset refresh time, after that they are static. You'll need to look at using Measures. Explain what you are needing in terms of visualisation.

Comment: I wanted to create a visualization showing top N customers and make this dynamic with a filter. I did it with measures the issue I have is: 
I need to know top 5 for example overall throughout the years and then add the year values and see the volumes split by year of those top 5. When I was using the measure and adding the years it was calculating the Top N by year instead of overall

Comment: That is great, suggest you update the question and focus the ask on that. Hint: Look at both `ALL` and `ALLSELECTED` functions to be able to get the total regardless of dimension (year), in your measure.